# If a man works in govt office where picture of president is placed on wall. Is it shirk for the employee who works in the office?

Tags: fiqh, shirk

When I read our country's constitution, there i have seen that the president and prime minister image is placed on head of the govt office. In that case what kind of sin for the employee who worked in this office.

Comment: Why should it be sin or shirk? Explain!

Answer (score 1):

No it's not shirk. Shirk is ascribing partners to Allah.
Having an image of the President on the wall is not ascribing partners to Allah.

It's great to see that you are worried about being sinful and may you be rewarded by it.